# Save CURL result in a variable PHP

Tags: php, curl

I'm new to the whole CURL library in PHP and managed to successfully get post data from a website using the following code:

```
 <?php
    $postcode="6942GJ"; 
    $huisnummer="8";
    $marktsegment="27";
    $aansluiting="-";
    $url="http://notimportantforstackoverflow.com"; 
    $postdata = "postcode=".$postcode."&huisnummer=".$huisnummer."&marktsegment=".$marktsegment."&aansluiting=".$aansluiting; 
    $ch = curl_init(); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
    curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata); 
    $status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
    $result = curl_exec ($ch); 
    curl_close($ch);
    ?>
```

Which returns the following table:

```html
<table cellspacing="1" cellpadding="1" border="0">
        <tbody><tr valign="bottom">
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Ean code aansluiting
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Straatnaam
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Huisnr.
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Huisnr. toev.
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Woonplaats
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Postcode
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Bijzondere aansluiting
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Markt segment
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Naam Netbeheerder
            </td>
            <td class="resultHeader">
                Ean Netbeheerder
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="1">
            <td bgcolor="#FFFFFF" colspan="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="1">
            <td bgcolor="#FEEAD3" colspan="10"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="2">
            <td colspan="4"></td>
        </tr>
            <tr bgcolor="#E5F0E7">
    
            <td class="resultData">
                871687140007253845          </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                Pittelderstraat         </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                8           </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                                    &nbsp;
                            </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                DIDAM           </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                6942GJ          </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                NEE         </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                                    GAS
                            </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                Liander NB          </td>
            <td class="resultData">
                8716871000002           </td>
        </tr>
            </tbody></table>
```

I want to work with the resulting data specifically the resulting string "Liander NB" I want to make a var out of this result like so $beheerder ="Liander NB"; But I don't know how to make a variable out of the resulting CURL data.

Comment: you forgot to url encode the variables. you'll fetch the wrong url if say $aansluiting contains a space or & or <> special characters. check out `urlencode()` , or better yet, `http_build_query`

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option to make `curl_exec()` return the response.

```
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url); 
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true); 
$status = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE); 
$result = curl_exec ($ch);
```

Then you can use `DOMDocument` to parse the HTML in the response, and its methods to find the information you want in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks Barmar, I've added the returntransfer.
used a slightly diffrent approach with the PHPSimpleDOM parser but the result is the same, I just find it easier to work with as opposed to DomDocument.

```
<?php
$postcode     = ($_POST['postcode']);
$huisnummer   = ($_POST['huisnummer']);
$marktsegment = "27";
$aansluiting  = "-";
$url          = "xxxxxxxxx";
include('simple_html_dom.php');


$postdata = "postcode=" . $postcode . "&huisnummer=" . $huisnummer . "&marktsegment=" . $marktsegment . "&aansluiting=" . $aansluiting;

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $postdata);


// Create a DOM object
$dom = new simple_html_dom();
// Load HTML from a string
$dom->load(curl_exec($ch));

$gasleverancier = $dom->find('td', 38)->plaintext; // zero based index selector

$gasleverancier = trim($gasleverancier);
```