# Get Html with CURL

Tags: php, html, curl, screen-scraping

I have a problem with my curl :

I connect to a page with CURL. then I redirect myself to a page that is available when you are connected. and then I would like to retrieve information on this page. But how can I do to get the html code? I have the page that is displayed, but I can't get the source code for scrap

```
   $url = "https://www.mywebsite.com/porte_transferer.php";
curl_setopt ($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 0); 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

$result = curl_exec($ch);
```

return true with var dump

with that, i see the page, but idk how recover html for scrap my information

Thank for your help

Comment: Why are you adding `\n` to `$value`?  Which DOM parsers have you researched before asking this question?  "Scrapping" is not the same as "Scraping".  If `$result` is giving you want you expect, then this question is not at all about curl and is completely about how to parse an html string.  Please [edit] your question to show `$result`. Then completely remove all of the unnecessary details about curl (Yes, I mean your entire current question body.)

Comment: @mickmackusa idk, i see this in other website, but this part work, i just dont know how access to html with curl for find element

Comment: @mickmackusa i want get value of input on this page, i use curl because we need to be connected for get this information

Comment: @mickmackusa you want see the first result or the second one ?

Comment: We only need to see the earliest point of failure as part of a [mcve].

Comment: @mickmackusa i edit

Comment: @mickmackusa maybe i just need to add argument, i just want to get html, currently i have the page, if i see source code i see it and i want to get it

Comment: Are you asking how to return the data to the variable? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44400184/save-curl-result-in-a-variable-php

Comment: @user3783243 yes but that dont work. i find how to access to response on network but same, i dont find

Comment: This is unclear. Please explain in detail what you want and what you are getting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.example.com/");
$fp = fopen("example_homepage.txt", "w");

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FILE, $fp);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);

curl_exec($ch);
if(curl_error($ch)) {
    fwrite($fp, curl_error($ch));
}
curl_close($ch);
fclose($fp);
```

[source](https://topcoders.blog/?view=q&q_id=57)

Comment: ok that can be work, but how i can find my value, like <input name="planete" value="xxxx">, i want fing xxx, this change all the time